# Laravel 5.2 - не могу вывести файл, загруженный на сервер директория storage. Ошибка 404

Tags: laravel, файловая-система

видеовариант вопроса https://youtu.be/3wdNkKLoi0M

Файл загружен успешно. Но браузер не может его увидеть. Пробовал различные варианты.
Выдает ошибку 404.

```
/storage/big.png
/storage/app/big.png
/storage/app/public/big.png
/storage/public/big.png
/storage/app/public/avatars/big.png
...
```

В config/filesystems.php стандартно:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

openserver на windows - квадратик "только чтение" убрал.

Comment: По умолчанию корень - `/storage/app`. Вы переопределили как - `app`.  Какой будет теперь абсолютный путь к публичным папкам?

Comment: Не переопределял. Все из коробки ветки 5.2. По этим путям также не открывает: 

    `/app/big.png`
     `/app/public/big.png`

Comment: Странно, У вас апач, что в логах пишется?

Comment: Да. openserver - апач как понимаю. В логах ларавела по этому поводу ничего. В логах ngix нечто `"2017/04/22 11:43:10 [error] 7488#10120: *37 CreateFile() "c:/openserver/domains/q/m4/public/app/public/big.png" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: m4, request: "GET /app/public/big.png HTTP/1.1", host: "m4""`   . В логах apache вроде бы ничего нет на дату попытки открытия файла. файла htacces в ларавеле нигде нет - не нашел.

Comment: Ну вот, вы знаете где ищет, папочка наверняка не сушествует. Погуглите - где-то писалось, что нужен символичный линк public на  /app/public/

Comment: Да, опенсервер добавляет директорию public/ к хосту m4. Т.к. изначально в его настройках я прописал m4/public/ определять как m4 . Видимо в этом проблема. Но что интересно, файлы шаблона  он определял правильно, которые лежали в директории m4\public\images   . Видимо лучше в одну директорию все публичные файлы на выво в браузере и складывать.

Comment: Спасибо! Навели в правильное русло. Буду теперь внимательнее относиться к логам сервера. Проблема практически решена.

Answer (score 0):

Решилось с помощью товарища @0xdb . Т.к. на openserver в конфигурации вкладки "домены" я указывал директорию `domen/public/` выводить как корень `domen/` , то и все запросы с браузера сервер читает добавляя внутри к домену domen директорию `/public` .

Поэтому картинку `http://domen/app/public/big.png` он пытался вывести запрашивая `http://domen/public/app/public/big.png`

Решается добавлением в openserver соответствующей записи домена для директории с необходимыми файлами, либо прописыванием в config/filesystems.php  :
`'root' => public_path()`